# Вопрос по DOM в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть одна проблема с которой я очень часто сталкиваюсь при написании js кода. Объясню на пример. У меня сейчас есть несколько блоков разных цветов и для каждого нужно сделать полу-прозрачную маску при наведении.

```
<div class="test" >
  <div class="test-content" id="test-content-1"></div>
   <div class="mask" id="mask-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <div class="test-content" id="test-content-2"></div>
   <div class="mask"  id="mask-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="test" id="test-3">
    <div class="test-content" id="test-content-3"></div>
    <div class="mask"  id="mask-3"></div>
</div>

 .test{
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
}
.mask{
 position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
display: none;

}
```

Обычно я решаю это, присваивая id Для каждого div-a с классом mask и test и просто дублирую код.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-1').mouseover(function () { 
        $('#mask-1').css('display','block')
     });

 });
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-1').mouseout(function () { 
        $('#mask-1').css('display','none')
     });
 });
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-2').mouseover(function () { 
        $('#mask-2').css('display','block')
     });

 });
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-2').mouseout(function () { 
        $('#mask-2').css('display','none')
     });
 });

     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-3').mouseover(function () { 
        $('#mask-3').css('display','block')
     });

 });
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test-3').mouseout(function () { 
        $('#mask-3').css('display','none')
     });
 });
```

И такие задачи, где нужно реализовать одинаковый функционал с элементами с одинаковым классом встречаются постоянно и использую я вот такой костыльный метод. Это не очень удобно и один и тот же код постоянно дублируется с разными id. Как написать скрипт, таким образом, чтобы js сам получал нужный id у элементов с одинаковыми классами?То есть, чтобы можно было обратиться к элементу с классом "test" и "mask", вытащить у них id и уже вешать действия к элементам по полученному id. Надеюсь вопрос понятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в этом случае это можно реализовать вообще 2-мя строками в css без js

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: none;
}

.test:hover .mask{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Если более общий случай, то события можно вешать на класс, а не id

```js
$('.test').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).children('.mask').css('display', 'block')
});

$('.test').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).children('.mask').css('display', 'none')
});
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test-content"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, именно метод .children мне видимо и нужен был, спасибо огромное.